# Accessing Azure SQL Server using 1) Python (local script--not going to be Azure function), 2) pyodbc & 3) Azure user-managed identity

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, pyodbc

I've created a Python script on my local machine & I'm attempting to authenticate into an Azure SQL Server (serverless (i.e., not managed instance)). Rather than storing creds in code, I want to utilize user-managed identity (UMI) to authenticate into my SQL Server.

I created the UMI in Azure portal, assigned it to my SQL Server & gave it read, write & admin authorization in SQL server.

I'm utilizing pyodbc in my script & I believe I'm having trouble with the connection string. After reviewing documentation & vids I thought it might be the case I could simply use the UMI client id rather than using Key Vault (as I prefer not to use that if at all possible); similarly, I don't want to use the ODBC GUI Client (i.e., ODBC Data Source Administrator) to store creds if I don't have to.

My thought is at the very least I have to pass in the UMI client id string via the pyodbc connection string, but then again I really don't have a lot of experience with this.

Here is my connection string:

```
db_connect = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={pyodbc_driver}; SERVER={pyodbc_server}; DATABASE={pyodbc_db}; UID={pyodbc_umi_client_id}; Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi", autocommit=True)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> ...Failed to authenticate the user 'pyodbc_umi_client_id' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryMSI').\r\nError code 0xA190; state 41360\r\n (0); [CE267] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].  (258); [CE267] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [CE267] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response (258)")

For the UID, I've tried the client ID string from the UMI on the Azure portal. Additionally, I also tried importing the following from one of the Azure modules:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
...
pyodbc_umi_client_id = 'client_id' # client id string from umi in azure portal
db_umi_crd = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=pyodbc_umi_client_id)
```

Here is all the script with identifying info removed it somehow it is helpful:

```
"""Dec 27, 2021

Want to connect to SQL db by using Azure
user-managed identity (UMI).
"""

import datetime
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import pyodbc


# global vars
program_name = 'AZURE SQL UMI CONNECTION' 
original_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 27)


def main():
    """Run main part (i.e., all functions) of the program

    Arguments:
        None

    Returns:
        None

    Raises:
        None

    """
    print_header(program_name, original_date)
    db_work()


def db_work():
    """Connect to the db and do work

        Arguments:
        None

    Returns:
        None

    Raises:
        None
    """
    # connection string vars
    pyodbc_driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    pyodbc_server = 'tcp:server_url,1433'
    pyodbc_db = 'sql_db'
    pyodbc_umi_client_id = 'client_id' # client id string from umi in azure portal
    db_umi_crd = DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=pyodbc_umi_client_id)

    # connection string
    # db_connect = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={pyodbc_driver}; SERVER={pyodbc_server}; DATABASE={pyodbc_db}; UID={db_umi_crd}")
    db_connect = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={pyodbc_driver}; SERVER={pyodbc_server}; DATABASE={pyodbc_db}; UID={pyodbc_umi_client_id}; Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi", autocommit=True)

    # db cursor
    db_cursor = db_connect.cursor()

    # do work
    rows = db_cursor.execute('select * from orderitems').fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)


def print_header(program_name, original_date, border='*'):
    """Print header indicating name of program

    Arguments:
        Program name: Positional arg. This is global var.
        Original Date: Positional arg. Date script was originally created.
        Border: Keyword arg. Border that is to print around name of program.

    Returns:
        None

    Raises:
        None
    """
    program_name_len = len(program_name) + len(str(original_date))
    print()
    print(border * program_name_len)
    print(program_name, ' ', str(original_date))
    print(border * program_name_len)
    print()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you please let me know in which OS you are trying to use Linux ,Macos or windows

Comment: Also you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398441/cannot-connect-to-the-azure-sql-server-with-python?rq=1 , May it helps

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I'm on Windows 10; should have put that in there--sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Could you please let me know do you have Installed ODBC Driver version 13.1 in your window OS . Which is currently support on windows only

Answer (score 0):

> I want to utilize user-managed identity (UMI) to authenticate into my
> SQL Server.

As suggested by @Ondrej [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368554/azure-sql-with-managed-identity-user-assigned-failed-to-use-against-aad)

**Currently, the server identity for Azure SQL does not support user-assigned managed identities (UMI)**

Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15#purpose)

> The ODBC Driver on Linux and macOS before version 17.6 only supports
> Azure Active Directory authentication directly against Azure Active
> Directory. If you are using Azure Active Directory username/password
> authentication from a Linux or macOS client and your Active Directory
> configuration requires the client to authenticate against an Active
> Directory Federation Services endpoint, authentication may fail. As of
> driver version 17.6, this limitation has been removed.

If trying to authenticate using access token:

> The ODBC Driver version 13.1 only supports this authentication on
> Windows.

**EDIT:**
For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965056/in-python-is-it-possible-to-connect-azure-sql-server-using-active-directory-pas?rq=1)

Comment: I have ODBC 17.8 (2017.178.01.01). 

With support for user-assigned managed identity, the UMI can be assigned to Azure SQL Managed Instance or Azure SQL Database as the instance or server identity.

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-user-assigned-managed-identity

@Ondrej

Answer (score 0):

@AjayKumarGhose-MT

Received the following from Microsoft after using Microsoft Q&A:

> Thanks for using Microsoft Q&A!!
> You are getting this error as you cannot use either user assigned identity or >system assigned managed identity to access from SQL server from you local >environment as these identities are meant for accessing Azure AD protected >resources from other Azure services like Azure functions, web apps etc.

> Please refer to managed identities documentation for details.
> You need to either provide the username and password in the code or you can >store these as environment variables.